# Is it possible to serve top-level buildscript dependencies using Artifactory?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, artifactory

Here is a sample top-level `build.gradle` configured with Artifactory:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:x.x.x"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:x.x.x'
    }
}
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
}
artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    //... standard artifactory plugin auto-generated from web interface
}
```

I would like `com.android.tools.build:gradle:x.x.x` and  to be served from an Artifactory remote, rather than from `jcenter` or the Google Maven Repository since these are blocked by a hostile workplace proxy.

However, it seems that the `artifactory` Gradle plugin is only available after the `buildscript` closure has been applied. How can I get the other `buildscript` dependencies to be served from Artifactory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make simple Maven remote repositories to serve the `buildscript` dependencies. Since these remote repositories simply mirror the public repositories, you can make the access anonymous. This means that at the time for executing the `buildscript` closure, there is no need for configuring `artifactory_user` and `artifactory_contextUrl`.

A sample `build.gradle` would look something like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http:///example.com:8082/artifactory/list/jcenter/"
        }
        maven {
            url "http://example.com:8082/artifactory/list/google-remote/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:x.x.x"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:x.x.x'
    }
}
```

where `google-remote` is the name (repository key) of the remote repository mirroring the Google Maven Repository you have configured yourself.

As for configuring the Artifactory remote for the Google Maven Repository itself, the address is simply `maven.google.com` as per the picture below:

[image: set up for remote of Google Maven Repository]